# how to catch drop event in QtableWidget in pyqt

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have a window with 3 table widgets designed using Qt Designer.

Table 1. To display groups that are present

Table 2. To display all employees (Drag Enabled setto True)

Table 3. To display employees in the selected group (AcceptDrops Set to True)

I want to catch drop event on Table 3. that is after a drop has performed i want to run a function. and at the same time it should avoid duplicates in the drop.

i have set eventfilters

```
Table3.installEventFilter(self)
```

but could not able to catch drop event.

my eventfilter def is as below

```
def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if (object is self.TBLW_GroupMembers):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragEnter):
            if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
                event.accept()   # must accept the dragEnterEvent or else the dropEvent can't occur !!!
                print "accept"
            else:
                event.ignore()
                print "ignore"
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop):
            print 'drop'
        return False # lets the event continue to the edit
    return False
```

I have followed this process posted from this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001944/pyqt-drop-event-without-subclassing)

Able to catch `DragEnter` but not `Drop`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to handle (and accept) `QtCore.QEvent.DragMove` events. You should probably also add a handler for `DragLeave` but I think that is less important.

Unfortunately this requirement doesn't seem to be documented very well, but I've observed a similar behaviour when I've implemented drag-and-drop. Personally, I typically just override the `dragEnterEvent()`, `dragMoveEvent()` and `dropEvent()` methods of the widget in question (rather than installing an event filter) but the principle is the same (and thus I expect the solution is the same).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is very old but maybe someone else could use the solution to this:
The Views sometimes have a viewport() that is used for the event handling. They take the eventfilter as well. So you just add

```
Table3.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
```

Now you should be able to catch the drop event.
Also keep in mind that your new object is the viewport so you have to change the line

```
if (object is self.TBLW_GroupMembers.viewport()):
```