# pyside capture when drag-n-drop event finished

Tags: python, pyside

What I want to do is call a function when the drop-event is successful. I've been able to print a statement 'Finished' when it's done. However the TreeWidget no longer continues to preform it's default operations. If i comment out my custom **dropEvent** it works as expected. But i want to call a function. What do i need to modify to maintain the original dragNdrop functions while calling an additional action.

```
# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg

class TreeNodeItem( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent, name="" ):
        super( TreeNodeItem, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setText( 0, name )

class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.setAnimated(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print "finished"

    # def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    #     print "finode" 


# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.resize(250, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # widget - passes treewidget
        self.itemList = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.itemList = TreeWidget()

        headers = [ "Items" ]
        self.itemList.setColumnCount( len(headers) )
        self.itemList.setHeaderLabels( headers )            

        # layout Grid - row/column/verticalpan/horizontalspan
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.itemList, 0,0,1,1)

        # display
        self.show()

    # Functions
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "closed"


    def showEvent(self, event):
        print "open"
        for i in xrange(20):
            TreeNodeItem( parent=self.itemList , name=str(i) )

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `dropEvent`, replacing the default one of `QTreeWidget` by the one you defined.

To keep the default behaviour and add something, you need to call the default `dropEvent`, just as you call the default `__init__`:

```
def dropEvent(self,event):
    super(TreeWidget,self).dropEvent(event)
    print("finished")
```

You can also use an event filter instead of overriding dropEvent, see [PyQt Drop Event without subclassing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001944/pyqt-drop-event-without-subclassing)